# Conditionally strip the last line from a text file

Tags: c#, file, text, line

I posted this yesterday on SO, and I received an answer that works great, but I need to change it around and I don't know how.

Here is my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878242/strip-the-last-line-from-a-text-file):

---

*I need to strip the last line from a text file. I know how to open and save text files in C#, but how would I strip the last line of the text file?*

The text file will always be different sizes (some have 80 lines, some have 20).

How to do this?

---

Here is the code that someone gave me to do this (which works fine)

```
//Delete the last line from the file.  This line could be 8174, 10000, or anything.  This is from SO
string tempfile = @"C:\junk_temp.txt";

using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(newfilename))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(tempfile))
    {
        string line = reader2.ReadLine();

        while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
        {
            writer2.WriteLine(line);
            line = reader2.ReadLine();
        } // by reading ahead, will not write last line to file 
    }
}

File.Delete(newfilename);
File.Move(tempfile, newfilename);
File.Delete(tempfile);
```

---

How would I change this to only delete the last line of the text file if it is a 4 or 5 digit string (such as 8001 or 99999).

If it is anything other than that, such as a %, then I don't want to delete the last line.

Can someone please modify the above code to do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the same logic as you have in the current code you could do the following

```
        //Delete the last line from the file.  This line could be 8174, 10000, or anything.  This is from SO 
        string tempfile = @"C:\junk_temp.txt"; 

        using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(newfilename)) 
        { 
            using (StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(tempfile)) 
            { 
                string line = reader2.ReadLine(); 

                while (!reader2.EndOfStream) 
                { 
                    writer2.WriteLine(line); 
                    line = reader2.ReadLine(); 
                } // by reading ahead, will not write last line to file  

                // If the last line read does not match your condition
                // we write it to the new file
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d{4,5}$"))
                {
                    writer2.WriteLine(line); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        File.Delete(newfilename); 
        File.Move(tempfile, newfilename); 
        File.Delete(tempfile);
```

Comment: I think you need a final $ in your regular expression, so that it doesn't match any line that starts with 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put in a conditional check after

```
line = reader2.ReadLine();
```

to check of EndOfStream and if this is true, your conditional check for the line (either a RegEx or line.Length == 5).

Answer (score 0):

Create a RegEx that matches a 4 or 5 digit string and filter your line removal on that. There are tons of good site online for C# RegEx practice/learning.

Answer (score 0):

Add that after the end of the `while` loop :

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d{4,5}$"))
    writer2.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` to:

```
while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader2.ReadLine();
    if (reader2.EndOfStream && (CheckIfNeedToDeleteLine(line) == false))
    {
        writer2.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

You will need to implement `CheckIfNeedToDeleteLine(line)`.

```
bool CheckIfNeedToDeleteLine(string line)
{
    int digit = 0;
    return (((line.Length == 4) || (line.Length == 5)) &&
        (int.TryParse(line, out digit)))     
}
```

`Regex` implementation of `CheckIfNeedToDeleteLine`:

```
bool CheckIfNeedToDeleteLine(string line)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d{4,5}$"); 
}
```

No idea which is more efficient but it wouldn't really matter since it would only happen on the last iteration because of the order of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reluctant to "modify the code" directly for you, but I'll give you a pointer.

```
string line = reader2.ReadLine();

while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
{
    writer2.WriteLine(line);
    line = reader2.ReadLine();
} // by reading ahead, will not write last line to file
```

Right after the last brace `}` in this code, you have the last line of the file in the variable `line`.  In your current code, this line gets thrown away.  I'd suggest that you insert an "if" statement here, comparing this last line to your criteria.  You could use a regular expression for this, something like `^[0-9]{4,5}$` should be suitable.

If the criteria is met, just call `writer2.WriteLine(line);` one more time for the last line.

Answer (score -1):

```
        string tempfile = @"C:\junk_temp.txt";

        using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(newfilename))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter(tempfile))
            {
                string line = reader2.ReadLine();

                while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
                {
                    writer2.WriteLine(line);
                    line = reader2.ReadLine();
                } // by reading ahead, will not write last line to file 
                int result=0;
                if (Int32.TryParse(s, out result) )
                {
                    if (s.Length != 4 || s.Length != 5)
                       writer2.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }

        File.Delete(newfilename);
        File.Move(tempfile, newfilename);
        File.Delete(tempfile);
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo: `The name 's' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Also `s.Length != 4 || s.Length != 5` will always be true.