# Is there an equivalent to mmap.mmap.rfind in C#?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, translate

While looking at memory-mapped files in C#, there was some difficulty in identifying how to search a file quickly forward and in reverse. My goal is to rewrite the following function in the language, but nothing could be found like the `find` and `rfind` methods used below. Is there a way in C# to quickly search a memory-mapped file using a particular substring?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import mmap
import pathlib


# noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
def drop_last_line(path):
    with path.open('r+b') as file:
        with mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as search:
            for next_line in b'\r\n', b'\r', b'\n':
                if search.find(next_line) >= 0:
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError('cannot find any line delimiters')
            end_1st = search.rfind(next_line)
            end_2nd = search.rfind(next_line, 0, end_1st - 1)
        file.truncate(0 if end_2nd < 0 else end_2nd + len(next_line))
```

Comment: For the Python stunted, can you describe what you're actually trying to achieve? Is it just finding if a given file contains a certain string?

Comment: @Jamiec No, it is trying to remove the last line of a CSV file where each line is terminated with a line delimiter. The following questions have unacceptable solutions because they process the entire file: (1) [How to delete last line in a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4264117/216356), (2) [How to Delete the last line of a file.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14960392/216356), (3) [Efficient way to delete a line from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/532217/216356)

Comment: The point of memory-mapped files is that once they are mapped, you can forget that the source is a file and use _whatever_ memory search function or algorithm you wish.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files

Comment: @MickyD Do you know of any way to memory-map an entire file in C# and then treat it as a byte array? After looking at the source code for the `find` and `rfind` methods, it does not appear that it would be too difficult to create a C# version of them if an array was available. Am I looking for the [UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadByte Method (Int64)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemoryaccessor.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way in C# to quickly search a memory-mapped file using a particular substring?
>
> Do you know of any way to memory-map an entire file in C# and then treat it as a byte array?

Yes, it's quite easy to map an entire file into a view then to read it into a single `byte` array as the following code shows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sourceFile=  new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Micky\Downloads\20180112.zip");
    int length = (int) sourceFile.Length;  // length of target file

    // Create the memory-mapped file.
    using (var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(sourceFile.FullName,
                                                     FileMode.Open, 
                                                     "ImgA"))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[length]; // allocate a buffer with the same size as the file

        using (var accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor())
        {
            var read=accessor.ReadArray(0, buffer, 0, length); // read the whole thing
        }

        // let's try searching for a known byte sequence.  Change this to suit your file
        var target = new byte[] {71, 213, 62, 204,231};

        var foundAt = IndexOf(buffer, target);

    }
}
```

I couldn't seem to find any byte searching method in `Marshal` or `Array` but you can use this search algorithm **[courtesy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/15514c1a-b6a1-44f5-a06c-9b029c4164d7/searching-a-byte-array-for-a-pattern-of-bytes?forum=csharpgeneral)** of **Social MSDN** as a start:

```
private static int IndexOf2(byte[] input, byte[] pattern)
{
    byte firstByte = pattern[0];
    int  index     = -1;

    if ((index = Array.IndexOf(input, firstByte)) >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            if (index + i  >= input.Length ||
                pattern[i] != input[index + i]) return -1;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

...or even this more verbose example (also courtesy Social MSDN, same link)

```
public static int IndexOf(byte[] arrayToSearchThrough, byte[] patternToFind)
{
    if (patternToFind.Length > arrayToSearchThrough.Length)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearchThrough.Length - patternToFind.Length; i++)
    {
        bool found = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < patternToFind.Length; j++)
        {
            if (arrayToSearchThrough[i + j] != patternToFind[j])
            {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your search algorithm is not one of the best. Using the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889427/search-longest-pattern-in-byte-array-in-c-sharp/9890164#9890164) you will likely see 5-8x speed ups.

Comment: Thanks for the example code! I will probably wait another day before accepting an answer to see if any other ideas are presented.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's because it's not mine as indicated

Comment: @MickyD I know, what I am trying to say is finding a example of Boyer-Moore and showing that would be better.